Access rights differentiation using DFS
I deployed DFS for convenience and faced the problem of assigning access rights to users.
The scheme is simple: 1-a global shared folder, it contains folders by year, they already have projects by name and there are 3 folders in the projects.
How to properly make access so that everyone can see the global sphere + folders by year and project folders, but access to folders inside projects was available only to whom you allow?
Now it turns out that in order to do something on the ball, you need to give access rights to the global ball and not to folders inside the project
You need to assign access to folders within the project and not to the global sphere[enter image description here]enter image description here

"global sphere"? "ball"? what is this about? Linux file permissions? Can you tag your question to indicate what these terms are about? Also, "I deployed DFS": what does that mean? You coded in some programming language (which?) an algorithm that traverses the file system in DFS order?

I apologize.Windows folder sharing
